# Location updates not working in background using iphone sdk 4

Tags: background, geolocation, ios4

I am trying to add the background location updates (i.e. the feature where applications running in background can still receive continuous lcoation updates) into my iPhone app. I implemented (in the view controller) the location update methods *didUpdateToLocation* and *didFailWithError*. I also added to the Info.plist file, the UIBackgroundModes key with the value 'location' in its string array. I have added the methods like *applicationWillResignActive*, *applicationDidEnterBackground*, *applicationWillEnterForeground*, *applicationDidBecomeActive*, *applicationWillTerminate* in the application delegate class, but I have kept them empty.

However when I run my app on an iPodTouch or an iPhone simulator, the application does not receive updates when its in background. It receives updates when in foreground. Also, when I bring the app back into foreground, there is a flurry of updates, like 5-6 updates at the same time.

Could you please point out what I am missing ? Does keeping the methods in delegate (which I mentioned) empty causes this ?

Thanks,
Abhinav.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement you location manager delegate, i.e. didUpdateToLocation etc, in the app delegate. See this answer for detail:

[to run app continuously in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947785/to-run-app-continously-in-the-background/6450804#6450804)