# Get background location updates every 5 minutes

Tags: ios, core-location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: Get location update every n minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/ios-get-location-update-every-n-minutes)

How can I get location updates in the Background every 5 Minutes?

Comment: Downvoted because this question shows no research effort at all. @user927298, there's basically two ways how you could have done better: **1.** Use the search facility on SO to find existing questions concerning this particular issue. There's no reason to ask something that's been answered before. **2.** If you find your question has *not* been asked before, don't just ask the question; also give some information what you have already tried, so that you won't get duplicate advice or random guesses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read the section **Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks** of in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).
And then pursue either **register for significant location changes** or **declare itself as needing continuous background location updates**.

Furthermore a solution to this problem was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/ios-get-location-update-every-n-minutes) by [wjans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665657/wjans).
And I quote:

> Found a solution to implement this with the help of the Apple
>   Developer Forums. I did the following:
>   •Specify location background
>   mode
>   •Use an NSTimer in the background by using
>   UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
>   •In case n is
>   smaller than UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining it does works just
>   fine, in case n is larger, the location manager should be enabled (and
>   disabled) again before there is no time remaining to avoid the
>   background task being killed. This does work since location is one of
>   the three allowed types of background execution.

Good luck :)