# How to call the webservice in the application background mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, background, call

I am developing one iPhone application, now i want to get the current location of the latitude and longitude in the **background mode**. So how can i get the lat/long values? After getting the latitude and longitude values, i need to pass those values to the server in the background mode. **Is any possible to call the web service in the application background mode?**

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to track the location, but you'll not be able to connect to your web-services when the app is in the background.

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)