# How do I get a background location update every n minutes in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I appreciate that this question already appears to have been answered here:
[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

However, although the solution is hinted at, I'd be really grateful if someone could post some sample code as to how this actually works.

Many thanks,

Jack

Comment: @wjans - could you possibly help here with the code that you ended up using? Many thanks!

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Have you achieved this task?? please share the info !! I will be really thankful

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to core location during application start.

some thing like this

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

and add delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I've got the main part of this sorted. I've set up a button that, when pressed, gets the current location and passes a post request to a server. What I want is for this to then happen automatically once every 30 minutes when the app is in the background.

Comment: The core location delegate will be get called even when app is in background.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works but the problem is I want the updates to be quite far apart (e.g. once per hour) and this eats a lot of battery life. Is there a way of firing the location manager and then stopping it again with long intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you will get the lattitude and longitude updated..in didUpdateToLocation...

```
//in view did load 

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy  = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0f;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
appDelegateObj.latitude= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    appDelegateObj.longitude = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
  }
```

Comment: Just posting the same comment as above. Thanks for your help:

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I've got the main part of this sorted. I've set up a button that, when pressed, gets the current location and passes a post request to a server. What I want is for this to then happen automatically once every 30 minutes when the app is in the background.

Comment: so you can add button and on button press call this call thread for 30 min. so every 30 min thread  will b call its own action and add this method in thread action so it will b call in every 30 min..