# iPhone Multitasking - how to make 'location' service updates "user optional"

Tags: iphone, location, multitasking

Considering the impact on battery, I would like to let users decide if the functionality of my app is something they want all the time as in "multitasking/background execution" or just when the app is in the foreground.  Reading this thread:

[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

gave me some ideas about what might be the best way to provide a user option to enable the multitasking function.  I am hoping someone who has considered this dilemma may have a suggestion on the "best way" to go about it.

*Problem*  - Location multitasking is enabled via the plist by setting the UIBackgroundModes item to 'location'.  This is app-wide and permanent.  How to make the function correspond to a NSUserDefault?

*Potential Solution A* - My proposal goes something like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"wantsBackgroundLocationEventProcessing"] ) {
        //Continue using the location subsystem
    } else {
        self.locationManager = nil; //Custom setter does all required cleanup
    }
}
```

However, my fear is that in this case the app will still receive location events, it simply won't be able to actually do anything with them - the effect on battery life will still be present.

Any ideas on how to make UIBackgroundModes 'location' optional during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the setting in plist just tell the iOS you need background update on location WHEN NEEDED. please check out the document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW7) for better understanding.

the     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] will continuously update location change, when you does not need it any more, just use [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] to turn off GPS to conserve battery.

or use [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] to get notified when significant change happened.

Comment: So you are basically accepting "Proposal A", which is that if I turn off location updates when entering the background then my app will not actively be registered and keep the location system draining the battery, regardless of the plist setting.  I have been verifying that it works this way in practice, but am still not sure about whether the system is actually *off*, or just off for my app (assuming no other apps on the device).  I do believe this answer is correct - can you confirm the latter point?

Comment: the answer is yes, use [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] first, then release your locationManager.

Comment: All my tests confirm you are absolutely correct.  The docs you reference were ambiguous to me but knowing the right answer now I see they do state the truth.  Thanks!