# update location in background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on walking track type app but facing problem that how location would upadte when app is in background . I am drawing a path on map as location update and a timer also .
Then please  suggest me how  i handle it.
here is my code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{  
    if(!newLocation) return;

    if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
        (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    {        
      // to  draw path as new location find
        jogPoint = [[JogPoint alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];

        [jogPoints addObject:jogPoint];


         if([jogPoints count] >= 5) {

            [self.mapView addOverlay:jogPoint];

            CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:oldLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:oldLocation.coordinate.longitude];


            CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            // returns distance in meters
          distnc+=[loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2] ;
            distanceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf",distnc];

       //  jogInfo.distance += ([loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2]) * 0.000621371192;

           // jogInfo.eclapsedTime = (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime) * 1000 * 60;



        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If your Application is in background mode also location is tracking/update as like if your app. active so don't worry about it :)

Just Make sure your create `CLLocationManager` such like

```
self.currentLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.currentLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
self.currentLocation.delegate = self;
[self.currentLocation startUpdatingLocation];
```

**EDITED :**

If here set `distanceFilter` then your method call at specific meter which value set in `distanceFilter` otherwise it update whenever your device is move

**And This is very important** to *set/add* `Require background mode` in `YourProjectName-Info.plist` file
Value is `App Registers for location update`

Such like

[image]

Comment: Would it update timer and there is no need to add required background mode in info.plist file.

Comment: didUpdateToLocation automatically call on your movement if distanceFilter is kCLDistanceFilterNone.

Comment: you mean to say i don't need to do any additional code for it.

Comment: @Arpi - Yes i', exactly :)

Comment: Make sure that your distanceFilter is not set and also does not stop `stopUpdatingLocation` so.. it will continue call `didUpdateToLocation ` method

Comment: @Arpi - now check my full correct answer :) your `didUpdateToLocation` method call even your application is in background mode :)

Comment: K Let me Check @iPatel

Comment: I have done with it. But I am not getting further process/code as discussed in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235203/getting-user-location-every-n-minutes-after-app-goes-to-background

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37260/discussion-between-ipatel-and-arpi)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the significant-change location service to receive location events.**

> This service offers a significant power savings and provides accuracy
>   that is good enough for most apps. It uses the device’s cellular radio
>   to determine the user’s location and report changes in that location,
>   allowing the system to manage power usage much more aggressively than
>   it could otherwise. This service is also capable of waking up an app
>   that is currently suspended or not running in order to deliver new
>   location data.

**To use the significant-change location service:**

> Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class, assign a delegate
>   to it, and call the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method
>   . As location data becomes available, the
>   location manager notifies its assigned delegate object. If a location
>   update has already been delivered, you can also get the most recent
>   location data directly from the CLLocationManager object without
>   waiting for a new event to be delivered.