# Send GPS coordinate every n minutes to a web service in background in Ios

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I am also developing a continuous **GPS update within n minutes**. The problem is complicating when I also need to **send that GPS coords to my Web Service**. Is it possible? I read somewhere that it's **impossible to use internet service while in Background mode**. I got some idea from here: [How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

Regards