# How to get current location latitude and longitude if application running in Background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am Working with CLLocation manager,

I have implemented `startUpdatingLocation` method for getting current location latitude and longitude.

I got latitude and longitude of current location if application running Foreground but, when application running in Background it's not work.

Please suggest me how i got the current location latitude and longitude if application running in Background.

Comment: A word of warning though. This is very bad for your battery life, so be sure you aren't getting the location frequently or  accurately there. If users think they left your app, but find out that their battery drains rapidly, they won't be happy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

i just found answer in stackoverflow from this link:-

[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application/6465280#6465280)

Found a solution to implement this with the help of the Apple Developer Forums.  I did the following:

- Specify location background mode
- Use an `NSTimer` in the background by using `UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`
- In case `n` is smaller than `UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining` it does works just fine, in case `n` is larger, the location manager should be enabled (and disabled) again before there is no time remaining to avoid the background task being killed.  This does work since location is one of the three allowed types of background execution.

**Note**: Did loose some time by testing this in the simulator where it doesn't work, works fine on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Get currcnt Location in backround Specify location background mode in plist.