# is it possible to track location even if application is not running

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In an iPhone application, is it possible to track location and send it to the server even if the application that has permission to location is not running in the background.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I can definitely say that it IS possible, you just might not be able to get that application submitted to the appstore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible — see [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for multitasking in general and this [section of the Location Awareness Programming Guide for "Getting Location Events in the Background"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10). Of course, all these talk about all of the various ways an iOS device can get your location (cell tower triangulation, Skyhook-style wifi network observation and GPS), not exclusive GPS.

In short, from reading those docs: add the UIBackgroundModes key into your info.plist, which is an array, and put the value 'location' into it. You'll then receive CLLocationManager updates even when in the background.

However, if you want to be nice to the battery then you're better off using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method on a CLLocationManager. Then you get suitably significant location updates even when in the background without being a full on background app. Other parts of the documentation state that a significant change is any change from one cell tower to another.

Comment: But if the application is not running in the background, then is it possible ?

Comment: How could your application do anything if it is not running on either the foreground or background?

Comment: You could do [region monitoring](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).. where you register for an area (a point and a radius) and ios will tell you when you come to that area.. or leave that area... but I do not kno if thats you wanted.. or you wanted to track the user as he moves along..

Comment: True, GeoFencing will open your app once you "enter" or "exit" a certain predefined area but it is up to the OS to fire the notification, not the app.

Comment: I read your answer with great amusing.  It is because the OP clearly stated in the question..."is not running in the background ".  I thought I would have discored some breakthrough ...

Comment: Then how do these guys do it? please see [http://www.stealthgenie.com](http://www.stealthgenie.com)

Comment: After watching their video, I have no other option but to think they are running using private APIs and that's why also, I couldn't find it on the app store. 

Actually, after a few more minutes of reading I found out [this from the FAQ](http://www.stealthgenie.com/faqs.html)

Does the target iPhone need to be Jailbroken before StealthGenie is installed on it?
Yes, the target iPhone needs to be jailbroken. Jailbreak process is extremely easy. You can find plenty of tutorials on the internet to guide yourself on how to jailbreak an iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

If the App is in the background, you can add a key-value pair in info.plist. The key is `UIBackgroundModes` and the value is like below :

[image]

Then do something in the background :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevicecurrentDevice];
    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
        backgroundSupported = YES;
    }

    __blockUIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTaskId];
        bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    if (backgroundSupported) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            //
        });
    }
}
```

But if the app is not even in the background, viz, not in the memory, then what can the app do? The CPU would not run a line of code of the app.

Comment: Then how do these guys do it? please see [http://www.stealthgenie.com](http://www.stealthgenie.com)

Comment: @user1630200 :) I saw it. But maybe the software is running in the background. It's beyond my imagination that a software can collect user info without running in the memory.