# Why my location service is not running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

My core location code is working fine all delegates are working properly, I can view exact location in mapview. Now I want this application to keep running in background, I searched on internet and found only few services are allowed to work in background and other suspend in few minutes. For enabling thos services I set a flag of `uibackgroundmode = location` and my delegate on core location is also working but still why my application suspends after running 20 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why this doesn't work. First try [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465280/361247) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application):

> - Specify location background mode
> - Use an NSTimer in the background by using UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
> - In case n is smaller than UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining it does works just fine, in case n is larger, the location manager should
>     be enabled (and disabled) again before there is no time remaining to
>     avoid the background task being killed. This does work since location
>     is one of the three allowed types of background execution.