# Keep an user checked in to current location from ios app in background

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

My application lets an user to check in to his current location. Also it has a feature of auto check in to the current location on logging in. And this can be viewed on a portal.

what i require is, even if the user quits the application, he should get checked in to the current location at short intervals of time.

Requirement is:

once the user gives permission for accessing the location, his/her current location should be accessible at any time from a server.
If not at any time, at least the location should be updated within intervals of 5 minutes.

The solution is very similar to the find my iPhone application. I want to track a device where my application is installed.

Comment: Did you happen to look at [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application?rq=1)?

Comment: oh! thanks.. i shouldn't have missed it.. my bad..