# How do I get a background location update every n minutes in ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager, background-process

My approach:

1. Start app in foreground and activate location manager
2. go to background: Stop location manager AND start a timer with e.g. call method every 10mins.
3. After 10min wake up start location manager and get new gps data

Without stopping the location manager bevor going to background it works!
But when not stopping location services it is constantly enabled (battery draining), I want to enable the location service every n minutes and immediately disable it.

Any hints/code what I have to call in applicationDidEnterBackground, to get awake e.g every 10mins.
I have the background modes location updates and BG fetch enabled.
There a lot of questions here with the same topic but in ios7 it seems to be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Periodic iOS background location updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates)

Comment: Here is a good example 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901583/start-location-manager-in-ios-7-from-background-task/18962839#18962839

Hope this help!