# What happens when app registers for location updates?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I just wanted to know what happens, when i select **app registers for location updates** under "**Required background modes**" in Xcode for an IOS app. 
**VOIP** provides **aliveTimeOutHandler** for specific duration. In same way, whether **location services** provides any **aliveTimeOutHandler** method? I am using IOS7

Comment: What it says in the apple docs ?

Answer (score 3):

When your app registers for location updates it will periodically check for location changes when in the background. Of course this is just a switch in project settings that enables that bground mode for your app. You need to actually implement the background task (write some code). You can see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901583/start-location-manager-in-ios-7-from-background-task) on how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you know how long app will check in background for location changes?

Comment: if you set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO (default is YES) it will keep updating while the app is in the background. Otherwise it will stop updating after about 15 mins in the same location.