# Make NSURLConnection async when app goes bakcground

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to do a simple NSURLConnection when application goes in background or when ends.
How can I do this ?
I dont' need to download anything or to do any long time operations, I only need to call an API from web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your applicationWillResignActive use -[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:] to start up a background network operation.  Be sure to call endBackgroundTask when you're done.  The major caution here is that you only have a short amount of time (10 seconds iirc) to finish up.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:

Answer (score 0):

If you can only need iOS 7 as a deployment target, you can use the background task API introduced in iOS 7. You can see it in action in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application/6465280#6465280).