# iOS 13.4 When app goto background from foreground network is getting disconnect

Tags: ios, ios13, swift5, ios13.3

***Steps to reproduce:***

1. Create a new app and call any API to the server to get data
2. immediately take the app to background
3. network get disconnects

***below is the log:***

2020-03-26 17:21:00.894598+0530 TestApp[783:152843] Connection 2: received failure notification

2020-03-26 17:21:00.895805+0530 TestApp[783:152843] Connection 2: failed to connect 1:53, reason -1

2020-03-26 17:21:00.895895+0530 TestApp[783:152843] Connection 2: encountered error(1:53)

2020-03-26 17:21:00.901375+0530 TestApp[783:152843] Task <36B9553A-99F2-42FE-8650-A5E5155EFCFD>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53])

2020-03-26 17:21:00.901831+0530 TestApp[783:152843] Connection 1: received failure notification

2020-03-26 17:21:00.902078+0530 TestApp[783:152843] [] nw_flow_add_write_request [C1.1 40.85.185.46:443 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] cannot accept write requests

2020-03-26 17:21:00.902200+0530 TestApp[783:152843] [] nw_write_request_report [C1] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"

2020-03-26 17:21:00.905902+0530 TestApp[783:152870] Task <36B9553A-99F2-42FE-8650-A5E5155EFCFD>.<1> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2824734e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.server.account, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.server.account, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Network operations are interrupted when your app is suspended. You can use `beginBackgroundTask` to get some additional execution time, but this is tens of seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. it would be helpful if you can share a sample code in Swift5.

Comment: I face the same issue and found the solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40254595/10709673