# Possible to send location update to BE in background mode?

Tags: ios, background-process

Curious is it possible to send GPS coordinates to the server, when iOS app is in background but background mode is turned on?

Comment: I really hoop that this is not possible, why would you, as an user, be able to turnoff background running for an app if it does not effect anything.

Comment: Because based on user's background location other users could interact with user with push notification and by tapping popup app could be launched.

Comment: But the user made a conscious decision to disable background running of apps. And that should be respected and I hope Apple's SDK does just this.

Comment: It ssems sending locations in background is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application?rq=1

Comment: I think you will just need to try it out. The user will first allow you app to track the location in the background. Which gives you app sometime to handle a location update. In this time you could sent to you server. I think that the disable background running only applies to periodically background fetching. Still there is noway to force background running.