# Data flows in after app opening with iOS/Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I started working on an existing app and noticed that the time "fast-forwards" when the app has been in the background for a long time. I shut it down at (example) 09:30 minutes, when I open it at 14:21 it did all of the work but only *then* it starts updating the UI. In a few seconds, it races through all of the data from five minutes in background.

This is not acceptable behavior for my app, so this is what I have done:

- Added background mode (location) to my capabilities
- Of course I linked CoreMotion to use the gyro/accelerometer.

  ```
  self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

  //Gyroscope
  if([self.motionManager isGyroAvailable])
  {
      // Start the gyroscope if it is not active already
      if([self.motionManager isGyroActive] == NO)
      {
          // Update us 2 times a second
          // [self.motionManager setGyroUpdateInterval:1.0f / 1.0f];

          [_motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:0.1];
          [self.motionManager
           startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
           withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
               if(error){

                   NSLog(@"%@", error);
               }
               else {
                   //NSString *x = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.02f",accelerometerData.acceleration.x];

                   float g = 9.80665f;
                   float AccelX = accelerometerData.acceleration.x * g;
                   float Accely = accelerometerData.acceleration.y * g;
                   float Accelz = accelerometerData.acceleration.z * g;

                   [self getSicknessIndicator:AccelX ay:Accely az:Accelz];
               }
           }];

          //Receive the gyroscope data on this block


      }
  }
  ```

I'm not quite sure why this behavior happens and I also tried out a lot of other questions on StackOverflow but with no result, unfortunately. They mostly tell me to add the background mode.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the background mode (location), you need to setup a location-manager and then call `startUpdatingLocation`, as long as your location-manager is capable to receive location-updates, your app will receive all device-motion updates in real time (even when phone is locked).

Here is the link to [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

Here is the link to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application) having sample code for location manager.