# What event will reset backgroundTimeRemaining?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, cllocationmanager

In the context of an application that has been registered to run in the background with the location services, what event(s) will result in backgroundTimeRemaining being reset to its maximum value and will that reset extend the duration allowed for the completion of ongoing tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? It looks like you want to [run continuously in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947785/to-run-app-continously-in-the-background).

Or maybe you just want to run a little bit of code when the location updates? Then don't "cheat the system" and run that code when your app is notified of a location change (and run it using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`).

Comment: Correct. I am interested in running continuously in the background. I read posts like the one you mentioned and that prompted me to ask this question to better understand my options: what exactly will or will not trigger a reset of that backgroundTimeRemaining. Is it a call to startUpdatingLocation? Is it any call to didUpdateLocations? Are there other events that will also reset that backgroundTimeRemaining?  Somehow I didn't see that stated explicitly anywhere and would like to know how things work before I use the code approaches supposed to meet my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Well I don't think you can and will get a correct answer, because Apple clearly does **NOT** want to tell people what triggers major `backgroundTimeRemaining` bonuses. I'm pretty sure this changes across iOS versions as well. Your options are to get notified on major loc changes, to run in the background using loc, or to use the hack to run continuously in the background.

Comment: Accepting your answer for making the good point that Apple probably doesn't document the answer to this question intentionally.  I will add what I observed experimentally in a separate answer.

Comment: Hi @Lolo, did you find anything with regards to this? I'm in a somehow similar situation right now.

Comment: @Cuevas. Sorry, I have moved on to other type of work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the experiments I ran on the simulator and hardware, and for the context I defined in the question,  backgroundTimeRemaining is reset whenever an internal call from the location library is made to didUpdateLocations (or didUpdateToLocation for IOS<6).

This is what all approaches used to running continuously in background leverage in one way or another.