# Background Location Services after reboot in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, background

I'm interested in a border line iPhone app able to detect the user location continuosly.
The app will be delivered in enterprise mode (so no Apple approval).

Basically it should run forever (resetting the backgroundTimeRemaining through the location service start end stop).

the issue that I was not able to fix is to relaunch the app after a reboot, event if I declare the voip capability, it seems that the system give me only 3 minutes, no more time despite all the workarounds.

so actually I'd like to know if someone was able to implement this sort of behaviour on iOS7.

thanks in advances, please find below some references.

[iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)

[to run app continuously in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947785/to-run-app-continously-in-the-background)

[Background Location Services not working in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7/21966662#21966662)

[Start Location Manager in iOS 7 from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901583/start-location-manager-in-ios-7-from-background-task?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it.
the music hack is the solution.

During the further 180s of background time a small mute playback of few seconds (of local mp3) restart the backgroundTimeRemaining counter.

bye